# Why does my Button not work with methods inside a class in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a button which is in a class that inherits from another class (which should be irrelevant here)
and the following code works perfectly with a button inside the class:

```
public class AttackState : State
{

    public AttackState(BattleSystem battleSystem) : base(battleSystem)
    {
        
    }
    
    public override void OnStateEnter()
    {
        Button btn = battleSystem.attackButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        Debug.Log("AttackState");
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => Debug.Log("heya"));
        Debug.Log(btn.gameObject.name);    
    }

    public void Attack() {
        Debug.Log("Attacking");            
    }
}
```

as soon as I change that to the following:

```
public class AttackState : State
{

    public AttackState(BattleSystem battleSystem) : base(battleSystem)
    {
        
    }

    public override void OnStateEnter()
    {
        Button btn = battleSystem.attackButton.GetComponent<Button>();
        Debug.Log("AttackState");
        btn.onClick.AddListener(() => Attack());
        Debug.Log(btn.gameObject.name);

    }

    public void Attack() {
        Debug.Log("Attacking");        
    }
```

It does not work anymore.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks fine. Can you provide some info on what's happening in the scene?

Comment: I have a battleSystem which is a GameObject in the scene. In my BattleSystem class I Start the State as StartState(new AttackState()) and the attackButton is a field of the BattleSystem class and I drag the Button on the attackButton field in the Inspector..

Comment: What about `btn.onClick.AddListener(Attack);` ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a Lambda Expression when you want to add a Function to your EvenListener.

Answer (score 0):

**How you should add a Method to a Listener:**

```
//Add a listener to the new Event. Calls MyAction method when invoked
m_MyEvent.AddListener(MyAction);
```

**Example with your Code:**

```
 btn.onClick.AddListener(Attack);
```

You shouldn't add parentheses as well as replace your Lambda Expression, with simply the name of the Function that should be called

[Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.AddListener.html)